# For non continuous functions there exists a net for which the "image-net" does not converge (Exercise)

Tags: general-topology, nets

I have a Question about the following exercise:

> Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ in $x_0$ not continuous. Proof that there exists a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $X$ such that for $x_i \rightarrow x_0$, $(f(x_i))_{i \in I} \nrightarrow f(x_0)$ in $Y$.

I am not sure if this exercise is just extremely easy or if I misunderstood something.
My Approach:
Lets $f$ be like above and assume that for every net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $X$ it follows that

(1)  $x_i \rightarrow x$, $(f(x_i))_{i \in I} \rightarrow f(x)$ in Y.

We know that the condition (1) is equivalent to $f$ being continuous in $x$. So we have a contradiction.

This exercise really seemed too straight forward, and I would be thankful for feedback.

Comment: If you know this theorem i.e.it's in your text so you can use it, then it's as easy as that, yes. For a concrete net that works look at the proof of that theorem...

Comment: As Henno said, if you know that (1) is equivalent to the continuity of $f$, then it does not remain to do an exercise in your question.

Comment: There is a difference between not being convergent to something and not being convergent to $f(x)$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks

Comment: @PaulFrost this was the reason I was so sceptical , thanks